# Generate a slug user name with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I create a manager creation form to create a manager.
I use slug from Str build-in class in Larave

I need to get the first name, last name, and phone number from the creation form and generate the username with the slug function and return to put the generated username to the username input field in the creation form.

**This is the Livewire Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Managers;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class GenerateManagerUsername extends Component

    {
        public $username = '';
        public $fname = '';
        public $lname = '';
        public $phone = '';
    
        public function render()
        {
            $this->username = Str::slug($this->fname . ' ' . $this->lname . ' ' . $this->phone);
            return view('livewire.managers.generate-manager-username', [
                'username' => $this->username,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**This is the Livewire View**

```
   {{-- A good traveler has no fixed plans and is not intent upon arriving. --}}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
        <label class="form-label" for="username">اسم المـــستخدم</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ $username }}"
            @error('username') style="border-color: red;" @enderror placeholder="أدخل اسم المستخدم" name="username"
            required="" readonly>
        @error('username')
            <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>
```

**And this is the creation form**

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" action="{{ route('managers.store') }}"
                            method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="row g-1">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="fname">الاسم الأول</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"
                                        wire:model="fname" @error('fname') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل الاسم الأول" value="{{ old('fname') }}" required="">
                                    @error('fname')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="lname">الاسم الأخـــير</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"
                                        wire:model="lname" @error('lname') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل الاسم الأخير" value="{{ old('lname') }}" required="">
                                    @error('lname')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                {{-- <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="username">اسم المـــستخدم</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                                        @error('username') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل اسم المستخدم" name="username" required="">
                                    @error('username')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div> --}}

                                @livewire('managers.generate-manager-username')

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="email">البريد الالكتـــروني</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                                        @error('email') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل البريد الالكتـــروني" value="{{ old('email') }}"
                                        required="">
                                    @error('email')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone">رقم الهـــاتف</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"
                                        wire:model="phone" @error('phone') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل رقم الهـاتف" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required="">
                                    @error('phone')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="DOB">تـــاريخ الميلاد</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB"
                                        @error('DOB') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        class="form-control flatpickr-basic flatpickr-input active  @error('DOB') wrong-input @enderror"
                                        placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly="readonly">
                                    @error('DOB')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="password">كلــمة المرور</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                                        @error('password') style="border-color: red;" @enderror
                                        placeholder="أدخل كلمة الرور" value="{{ $password }}" required="">
                                    @error('password')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="account_status">حـــالة الحساب</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" name="account_status" id="account_status"
                                        @error('account_status') style="border-color: red;" @enderror>
                                        <option value="0">*</option>
                                        <option value="active">فعــــال</option>
                                        <option value="inactive">متـــوقف</option>
                                        <option value="blocked">غـــير نشـــط</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @error('account_status')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-12 mb-3 position-relative">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="role_id">المسمــى الموظيفي</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" name="role_id" id="role_id"
                                        @error('role_id') style="border-color: red;" @enderror>
                                        <option value="0">*</option>
                                        @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                            <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @error('role_id')
                                        <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-float waves-light"
                                type="submit">إضافة</button>
                        </form>
```

**Note that I put the @livewireStyle in the styles block, and @livewireScripts in the scripts block.**

This is an image of what does I mean
[Creation Manager Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsTey.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to generate a username for the manager from its fname, lname, and phone

Comment: I think the problem is you're not assigning anything to fname, lname etc. So your username is just blank. How do you populate those?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass again `'username' => $this->username` in your render method.

It's already assign property as `public $username` in your `GenerateManagerUsername` class.

You can directly use it `$username` in your blade view file.

```
public function render()
{
    $this->username = Str::slug($this->fname . ' ' . $this->lname . ' ' . $this->phone);
    return view('livewire.managers.generate-manager-username');
}
```